# Optimal stopping for Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

If the problem of optimal stopping for finite state discrete time Markov Chains is solved on the infinite horizon explicitly?

**Edited:** This means if for a given MC $X(n)$ with a state space $x_1,...,x_n$, transition matrix $P$; and a vector $g_1 = g(x_1),...,g_n = g(X_n)$ there is an explicit solution to the problem
$$
v_i = \sup\limits_{\tau<\infty}\mathsf{E}[g(X(\tau))|X_0 = x_i].
$$

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you state your question more precisely?

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: This is still not a question

Comment: For an irreducible Markov chain, $v_i$ is $\max g(\ )$ for every $i$.

Comment: Hence $v_i$ does not depend on $i$. And an optimal stopping time $\tau$ is the first hitting time of the set argmax $g(\ )$.

Comment: For the irreducible it's trivial. The question was about an arbitrary MC.

Comment: Still trivial: replace the global maximum by the maximum on the connected component of the starting point $x_i$. (I read your last comment by chance, please use this @ thing.)

Comment: @Didier Piau, thanks. I am curious again for the vote down.

Comment: @Gortaur: You are welcome. Am I supposed to be related to the downvote?

Comment: @Didier Piau, I don't know. You just usually have a guess why it was downvoted (anyway comment "This is still not a question" is slightly incorrect)

Comment: @Gortaur: Am I supposed to be concerned by your guess? (Anyway, since you mention TheBridge's comment, I happen to disagree with the content of your parenthesis.)

Comment: @TheBridge: Just to let you know that you are mentioned in a little drama we seem to be having here (see last comments above).

Comment: @Didier Piau, thanks for redirecting ) I was thinking that everyone see new messages in his inbox regardless of @ thing - just because he already wrote a comment on this question. Now it seems more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is solved in a finite number of steps by so called the State Elimination algorithm (for Markov chains), see the papers of Isaac M. Sonin.

Comment: That's yours? Ok, thanks )